# Apache Poi appending data in excel adjacent to columns

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-poi

I have a list of objects (every object contains one string and another list of objects(this object contains two string)

I need to append data into excel sheet using Apache poi API

```
List<objects> -->String(ex:-Test profile1, List<objects> --> String(tab name ex :standard -account),String (ex :hidden/default off)
```

TabName                 Test Profile1   Test Profile2   Test Profile3   Test Profile4

standard-Account    Default Off Default Off Default Off Default Off
standard-Campaign   Hidden          Hidden          Hidden          Hidden
standard-Case           Default Off Default Off Default Off Default Off
standard-Contact    Default On  Default On  Default On  Default On

code i have written is working when size of list of objects(string,string ) changes it not working properly

```
HSSFRow rowTablevelHeader = null;
                HSSFRow rowtablevel = null;

            //check sheet name
            rowTablevelHeader = fourthSheet.createRow(0);

            HSSFCell cellT1 = rowTablevelHeader.createCell(0);
            cellT1.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("TabName"));

            /*int maxtablevelSize = listprofileTabLevelVisibilities.get(0).getTablevelVisibility().size();

            for (int i = 0; i < listprofileTabLevelVisibilities.size(); i++) {

            int tablevelSize1 = listprofileTabLevelVisibilities.get(i).getTablevelVisibility().size();

            if(tablevelSize1 >maxtablevelSize)
            {
                maxtablevelSize= tablevelSize1;
            }
            }
            */

            for (int i = 0; i < listprofileTabLevelVisibilities.size(); i++) {


                HSSFCell cellP1 = rowTablevelHeader.createCell(i+1);
                cellP1.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(listprofileTabLevelVisibilities.get(i).getProfileName()));

                int currentRow = 0;

    System.out.println("Size tablevel ---   "+listprofileTabLevelVisibilities.get(i).getTablevelVisibility().size());


                for (int j = 0; j < listprofileTabLevelVisibilities.get(i).getTablevelVisibility().size(); j++) {

                    currentRow++;

                    rowtablevel = fourthSheet.getRow(currentRow);

                    if(null == rowtablevel){
                        rowtablevel =fourthSheet.createRow(currentRow);
                    }

                    if(null ==rowtablevel.getCell(0))
                    {
                        HSSFCell cellAP1 = rowtablevel.createCell(0);
                        cellAP1.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(listprofileTabLevelVisibilities.get(i).getTablevelVisibility().get(j).getTabName()));   
                    }


                System.out.println("Tab name ---  "+listprofileTabLevelVisibilities.get(i).getTablevelVisibility().get(j).getTabName());

                if(rowtablevel.getCell(0).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase(listprofileTabLevelVisibilities.get(i).getTablevelVisibility().get(j).getTabName())){
                    HSSFCell cellAP2 = rowtablevel.createCell(i+1);
                    cellAP2.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString(listprofileTabLevelVisibilities.get(i).getTablevelVisibility().get(j).getTabVisibility()));
                }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your formatting is rather broken, any chance you could clean it up so that we can more clearly see what your question is, and what your code does?

Comment: yes formatting was broken.Anyhow i was able to solve the problem by adding a logic (loop upon a loop).Thank you